# How to convert Observable<Type> to Single<Type> in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I currently have a method that returns an observable. However, it only ever returns one element.

```
func getMyResponse(queryID: String) -> Observable<Response> {
    return observable
}
```

I am trying to refactor this code from returning `Observable<Response>` to `Single<Response>`.

```
func getMyResponse(queryID: String) -> Single<Response> {
    return observable.first()
}
```

The above is not working and gives the following error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, Response?>' to return type 'Single<Response>`.
```

**Anyone know how to fix this issue? Any insight would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Can you try the asSingle() operator?

func getMyResponse(queryID: String) -> Single<Response> {
    return observable.asSingle()
}

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan No. For some reason when I do that, I get this other error. `Value of type 'PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, Response?>' has no member 'asSingle'`. Not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the compiler that you will return a `Single<Response>` from the function, but you are actually returning a `Single<Response?>`. That's an error.

Note that `Single<Response?>` is a typealias of `PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, Response?>`.

For more information. You could do either of the following:

```
func option1(queryID: String) -> Single<Response> {
    return observable.asSingle()
}

func option2(queryID: String) -> Single<Response?> {
    return observable.first()
}
```

For `option1`... If the observable completes without emitting a value the Single will emit an error `RxError.noElements`. If the observable emits a second value before completing, the `asSingle()` will convert that second value into an error `RxError.moreThanOneElement`

For `option2`... If the observable completes without emitting a value, it will emit `nil` and complete. And the observable will be disposed before it gets a chance to emit a second value.